How to write the contents of a register to a file?
I have yanked a block of text to a register "a." Now, I want to write this register to a separate/unopened file in the Vim editor.

You have to open a file before you can access it; as a general rule.
The following commands will open a file and put register a's contents
:edit separate_file.txt
"aP

If you want to run from a script, you might be interested in a solution to achieve your goal with functions.
You can use the writefile() function like this:
call writefile([getreg('a')], 'separate_file.txt')

See :help writefile() and :help getreg() to access register a.

Thanks. There were couple of more workarounds which were suggested in other forum and which I already knew. But this works the best and I think can be implemented as a macro saved in .VIMRC.
